# function showing up as text in searchText field

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a angularjs ng-click function that filters the results of a list based on the searchText when a tab is clicked. However, Why does the function show up in the text box when clicking on one of the tabs and how to I prevent that from showing up? Thank you. The entire code can be seen on at [this](https://codepen.io/centem/pen/yLVOaMK?editors=1010) codepen.

AngularJS generated tabs

```
<span class="tab-span" ng-repeat="tab in tabs" ng-click="updateTab(tab.value,$event.currentTarget)">{{tab.label}}</span>
```

updateTab function

```
  $scope.tabs = [
        {value: undefined, label: 'All', },
        {value: 'Infrastructure', label: 'Infrastructure'},
        {value: 'CSI', label: 'CSI'},
        {value: 'EnterpriseSIEMContentCreate', label: 'Enterprise SIEM'}
    ];

    $scope.updateTab = function(filterText,element) {

        var spans = document.querySelectorAll(".tab-span");
        spans.forEach(span => {
            span.classList.remove("active-span");

        });
       element.classList.add("active-span");
       
        if(!filterText){
            $scope.searchText = filterText;
        } else {
            $scope.searchText = function(e) {
                return (filterText.indexOf(e.AssignedTo) !== -1);
            };
        }
    };

    $scope.defaultSpanView = function() {
        var sp = document.querySelectorAll(".tab-span");
        console.log(sp);
    };
    $scope.defaultSpanView();
```

Comment: `ng-model` doesn't accept a function but you are passing one to it when you assign a function to `$scope.searchText`

Comment: Create own  filter function where you will filter rows regarding searchText and selected tab